# Header location infinite redirect Loop

Tags: php

I have this huge issue that I have no idea how to fix. I have a script that redirects to a url.

So far I have:

```
//do some mysql
$geo_included = true; //trying to fix infinite redirect loop.
if($geo_included === true){
    header('Location: '.$url["url"]); //this is causing the issue with redirect loop
}
```

$url["url"] for example is: www.google.com

But when I go to that PHP file it will redirect to:

```
www.sitename.com/www.google.com
```

and say there is an infinite redirect loop. Note: the above header location script is not in a while/for/foreach loop.

Here is my .htaccess for the / directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?group=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Try putting exit; after the header statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the fully qualified domain name *with scheme*, otherwise it's interpreted as being in the current domain:

```
header('Location: google.com'); // Redirects to http://cursite.com/www.google.com
header('Location: http://google.com'); // Redirects as expected
```

If you are unsure if your URL includes a scheme, check the results from [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url).

```
$url_scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
// www.google.com -> NULL
// http://google.com -> string(4) "http"
// ftp://site.com -> string(3) "ftp"
```

Comment: @JakeGould - Edited to include `parse_url` to check the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The quick proof-of-concept solution here is to prepend  `http://` to the URL like this:

```
$geo_included = true;

if ($geo_included) {
    header('Location: http://' . $url["url"]);
}
```

I say “proof of concept” because what you should do is ensure the `$url["url"]` always has a protocol attached to it. Either before it gets into  the database, or in this code snippet by doing a check on the `$url["url"]` value to see of it has `http://` or `https://` and if it doesn’t, prepend it. And here is a quickly thrown together example of what I mean which should work:

```
$geo_included = true;

if ($geo_included) {
    $protocol = (!preg_match("~^(?:ht)tps?://~i", $url["url"])) ? 'http://' : null;
    header('Location: ' $protocol . $url["url"]);
}
```

The line with `$protocol = …` does the check I explained before. The default is to add `http://` if it’s not there.

Also, note I removed `=== true` since the `if ($geo_included) {` is basically the same thing.